# Why is performing disk I/O twice is faster than only reading files once

Tags: python, performance, optimization, time

I have a script that combines several whitespace-delimited files into one. Because of the format these files are generated in, I originally had the script reading headers first, then reading data. I assumed that performing disk I/O twice would slow down the function significantly, so I wrote a version that reads the files once, then performs the necessary manipulations to end up with the same table. To my surprise, this version performed worse! I am struggling to understand why reading the files twice is faster, and wondering if there is any clear reason I don't understand. Thank you!

The functions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import argparse
import config

header_rows = 2

def append_chroms(file_list) :
    chroms = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time', 'Signal', 'Channel', 'Sample'])
    for file in file_list:

        to_append = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace = True, index_col=None)

        sample_info = to_append.head(header_rows)
        sample_name = str(sample_info.loc[0]['SampleName'])
        channel_ID = str(sample_info.loc[0]['Channel'])

        to_append = to_append.iloc[1:, 0:2]
        to_append.columns = ['Time', 'Signal']
        to_append = to_append.apply(pd.to_numeric)
        to_append['Channel'] = channel_ID
        to_append['Sample'] = sample_name

        chroms = chroms.append(to_append, ignore_index = False)


    wide_table = chroms.copy()
    wide_table['Sample'] = wide_table['Sample'].astype(str) + ' ' + wide_table['Channel']
    wide_table.drop('Channel', axis = 1)

    wide_table = wide_table.pivot_table(
        index = 'Time',
        columns = 'Sample',
        values = 'Signal'
    )

    return (chroms, wide_table)

def old_append_chroms(file_list) :
    chroms = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time', 'Signal', 'Channel', 'Sample'])
    for file in file_list:
        to_append = pd.read_csv(
            file,
            delim_whitespace = True,
            skiprows = header_rows,
            names = ["Time", "Signal"],
            header = None
        )
        sample_info = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace = True, nrows = header_rows)
        sample_name = str(sample_info.loc[0]['SampleName'])
        channel_ID = str(sample_info.loc[0]['Channel'])
        to_append['Channel'] = channel_ID
        to_append['Sample'] = sample_name

        chroms = chroms.append(to_append, ignore_index = False)

    wide_table = chroms.copy()
    wide_table['Sample'] = wide_table['Sample'].astype(str) + ' ' + wide_table['Channel']
    wide_table.drop('Channel', axis = 1)

    wide_table = wide_table.pivot_table(
        index = 'Time',
        columns = 'Sample',
        values = 'Signal'
    )

    return (chroms, wide_table)
```

Timing their results on a list of 16 files:

```
In [11]: timeit.repeat(new_way, number = 1000, repeat = 3)
Out[11]: [161.06843920000006, 170.47517340000013, 169.0011060999998]


In [12]: timeit.repeat(old_way, number = 1000, repeat = 3)
Out[12]: [138.95367600000003, 139.55725690000003, 145.0546865]
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a [mre] (which is to say, the shortest possible code *someone else can run without changes* to reproduce your problem). For example, I don't see where `header_rows` is defined.

Comment: system and disc can keep file in memory (cache/buffer) and send it to you again from memory.

Comment: Also, be sure in benchmarking that your caches are either hot in all cases, or cold in all cases. If you're comparing algorithm-A with cold caches (data needing to be read from actual disk) with algorithm-B with hot caches (data in the block cache in your operating system's memory), the cache state can make far more difference than the algorithm does!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy missed that constant, thank you!

Comment: ...okay, so one of those two reads is tiny, almost certainly small enough to fit in a single page in the block cache. So that one's going to require a small, effectively-constant amount of time no matter what. Anything you're doing that slows the access patterns down in the other codebase to avoid that small constant cost is a place to look, then.

Comment: Thus, where I'd start is with a sampling profiler to figure out where time is actually being spent between the two cases. Something's making processing of the bulk data slower in your single-read codepath; to figure out what that something is myself, I'd first need to generate a sample data file (unless you're linking to one or generating test data in your code, and I just missed that), then run a sampling profiler against it myself.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy! I had never heard of a profiler before, and just gave py-spy a look. My guess as to what is slowing down the single-pass path is all the dataframe slicing and the type conversion I have to do, but it is honestly hard for me to read these profiles.

If you're interested in testing them yourself, there are test files in the github repo https://github.com/PlethoraChutney/HPLC_Scripts (not the 3D files) but I am satisfied learning about the cache, something I had not considered!

Comment: BTW, when I care about single-threaded number crunching performance, Python isn't the language I reach for at all. Familiar with [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/)?